# Conditional cell highlighting based on external list

Tags: javascript, r, datatables, dt

I want to highlight cells in a datatable on the condition that the values are contained in another list.

Here is my reproducible example:

```
library(DT)
library(tidyverse)

df_table <- tibble(
  id = 1:10,
  V1 = rnorm(10)
)

my_id_list <- c(4, 6, 8)

datatable(df_table)
```

Now I want to highlight the `id` values which are contained in the `my_id_list`:
[image]

The following code does not work, but should clarify my intention:

```
datatable(df_table) %>%
  formatStyle("id", backgroundColor = if(id %in% my_id_list) {"yellow"})
```

I am unsure whether a solution can be achieved with the help of R. Probably a solution with javascript makes the most sense, as shown in this issue:
[Implementing ifelse (or if_else) in datatable output to conditionally change the background color of a reactive table (shiny and r)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70955804/implementing-ifelse-or-if-else-in-datatable-output-to-conditionally-change-the)

Comment: Add a column `color = c("", "", "","yellow", "", "yellow", "", "yellow", "", "")` to your table. Then use `formatStyle` using `"color"` as the `valueColumns` argument. Finally hide this extra column for the rendering.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Unfortunately I can't create a solution on my dataset from your comment. Could you post a solution as an answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an extra column with binary coding, then using `styleEqual` to match on the binary column, but hide it in the actual DT table.

Reference from https://rstudio.github.io/DT/010-style.html

```r
library(DT)
library(dplyr)

datatable(data = df_table |> mutate(col = ifelse(id %in% my_id_list, 0, 1)),
          options = list(columnDefs = list(list(targets = 3, visible = FALSE)))) |> 
  formatStyle("id", "col", backgroundColor = styleEqual(c(0, 1), c("yellow", "")))
```

[image: DT]